# MFMailComposeViewControllerでメール送信しようとするとviewServiceDidTerminateWithErrorが発生してしまう

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

`MFMailComposeViewController` でメール送信しようとすると `viewServiceDidTerminateWithError` が発生してしまいます。
挙動としては、メーラーが起動して数秒後に元の画面に戻されます。

iOS7のシュミレータでは発生しません。
iOS8のシュミレータでのみ発生。

デバッガに出力されたメッセージはこちらです。

> viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7fce62f01f80 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

改善方法が分かる方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

ソースコードはこのような感じです。

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = (id)self;
[controller setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"mail_subject_about_view", @""),
                                                  NSLocalizedString(@"string_app_name", @"")]];

NSMutableString *messageBody = [NSMutableString string];
messageBody = @"test";
[controller setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`canSendMail` の判断は直前に入れています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS8のシミュレータでのみ発生する問題みたいですね。

`MFMailComposeViewController` を初期化してすぐに使うとこのようなエラーが発生するらしく、

- アプリが起動した時点で `MFMailComposeViewController` を初期化し、インスタンスを保持する
- メールを送信するときはその場で初期化する代わりに、用意しておいたインスタンスを使う
- 同じインスタンスは再利用せず、メール送信後に作り直す

という方法で回避できるようです。

参考: [ios - I have REAL misunderstanding with MFMailComposeViewController in Swift (iOS8) in Simulator - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25864182/2818869) （サンプルコードも載っています）

Comment: ありがとうございます！
教えていただいた方法で試してみます。

実機では発生しないという情報を私も発見したので、最悪実機のテストで発生しなければいいかなとも思っていますが。