# swift メール画面を閉じたい。

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift2

メールを立ち上げることはできたのですが、閉じることができません。
 switch result.value  のところにエラーメッセージが出ています。
調べてみても分からなかったので質問させていただきました。

よろしくお願いします。

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

```
    switch result.value  {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
       break
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どこで見つけられたコードか知りませんが、ずいぶん古い書き方をしていますね。Swift1.xのかなり初期の書き方になっています。

現在の`MFMailComposeResult`型はSwiftに以下のようにimportされています。

```
public struct MFMailComposeResult : RawRepresentable, Equatable {
    public init(_ rawValue: UInt32)
    public init(rawValue: UInt32)
    public var rawValue: UInt32
}
public var MFMailComposeResultCancelled: MFMailComposeResult { get }
public var MFMailComposeResultSaved: MFMailComposeResult { get }
public var MFMailComposeResultSent: MFMailComposeResult { get }
public var MFMailComposeResultFailed: MFMailComposeResult { get }
```

ご覧になればわかると思いますが`MFMailComposeResult`には、`value`という名前のプロパティはありませんから、そのせいでエラーになっています。**あなたのコードから全ての`.value`を削除してしまってください。**

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

    switch result  {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        break
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

初期のSwiftでは、Objective-Cからimportしたenum型の定数では`==`による比較もできなければswitch-caseにも使えないという、今から考えるとかなりひどい制約があったので`enum`内部の整数値(これも`value`から現在では`rawValue`に変更されています)を取り出して比較する必要があったのですが、現在のSwiftにはそのような制約はありませんので値(`result`)も比較する定数値(`MFMailComposeResultCancelled`等)も共に同じ型(今回は`MFMailComposeResult`)であれば、全てに`.value`をつけるような面倒はしなくても良くなっています。

Xcodeのエディター上で`MFMailComposeResult`をCommand-clickすれば上記の型定義のヘッダーは見ることができます。何もかも全て読み取れる必要はありませんが、「`MFMailComposeResult`型には`value`なんてプロパティがない」ことくらいは(そのような意味のエラーメッセージも出ていたはずです)理解できるようにしてください。

なお表題の「Swiftのメーラー」ですが、通常「メーラー」と言うと「メールの送受信機能を持った独立したアプリ」のことを言いますから、大変誤解を招きやすいタイトルになっています。正確な技術用語はわからなくても、`MFMailComposeViewController`を表示させているというのはコードを書かれたのだから分かっているはずです。タイトルにもそのクラス名を含めたほうが良いでしょう。(私は最初「メーラーのことなんて知らねぇよ」と思ってスルーしていました。)

また今回は自明な誤りがあったので回答が書けましたが、「エラーが出ています」と言う場合には必ず「ビルド時のエラーなのか実行時のエラーなのか」と「エラーメッセージの内容」をエラーが出た場所に加えて質問中に記載するようにしてください。

Comment: 大変わかりやすい説明ありがとうございます。
また、大変分かりにくい質問の書き方をしてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。
先ほど書いていただいた通りコードを書き直してみたのですが、ビルドしてみたところメールを立ち上げた瞬間に閉じてしまいました。
これはmacでテストしているからでしょうか？実機でテストすればできる問題でしょうか？
遅くにご迷惑おかけいたします。

Comment: あまり恐縮せずに今後改善していって下さい。本文も編集できるはずなので、よろしければこの質問内容の改善にもチャレンジしていただければと思います。さて、「ビルドしてみたところメールを立ち上げた瞬間に閉じてしまいました 」ですが、[MFMailComposeViewControllerでメール送信しようとするとviewServiceDidTerminateWithErrorが発生してしまう](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6940/mfmailcomposeviewcontrollerでメール送信しようとするとviewservicedidterminatewitherrorが発生してしまう)をチェックしてみてください。(タイトルのつけ方の参考にも。)また[iOS9のシミュレータはダメという話](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078073/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-throws-an-error-only-in-ios-9)もありますので実機でのテストをしてみてください。そこら辺を調べてもうまくいかない場合、今回のご質問とは別件として(今度は起動部分のコードを入れて)新しい質問を書き込んでみてください。